# SQL UNPIVOT two sets of columns based on string prefix

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I have the following table:

#### INPUT TABLE:

| id | value_0 | type_0 | value_1 | type_1 | value_2 | type_2 | value_3 | type_3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| id_1 | H | type_max | VH | type_min | VL | type_three | VH | type_four |
| id_2 | VH | type_max | VL | type_min | H | type_three | L | type_four |

I need to unpivot the input table into two separate fields: 'type' and 'value', where each new row has a type and value where the numeric suffix is the same. The resulting table must be the following:

#### OUTPUT TABLE

| id | parameter | category |
| --- | --- | --- |
| id_1 | type_max | H |
| id_1 | type_min | VH |
| id_1 | type_three | VL |
| id_1 | type_four | VH |
| id_2 | type_max | VH |
| id_2 | type_tin | VL |
| id_2 | type_three | H |
| id_2 | type_four | L |

In my head, the answer would be something like this, but obviously you cannot unpivot twice:

```
SELECT id, parameter, category
from input_table
UNPIVOT (
  parameter FOR type IN (type_0, type_1, type_2, type_3)
  category FOR value IN (value_0, value_1, value_2, value_3)
);
```

Comment: that is called pivot and not unpivot

Comment: This is indeed a type of unpivot, but there is no need for use of "unpivot" (or "pivot") in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need a method to force a single row into 4 rows, and then push the values into a single column. For this join to a CTE (or subquery) that has those rows and set the join conditions to force the extra rows in the output. The case expression then pushes the values into a single column.

```
with params as (
    select 'type_max'   as param union all
    select 'type_min'   as param union all
    select 'type_three' as param union all
    select 'type_four'  as param
   ) 
select
      t.id
    , params.param
    , case 
         when params.param = 'type_max'   then value_0
         when params.param = 'type_min'   then value_1
         when params.param = 'type_three' then value_2
         when params.param = 'type_four'  then value_3
      end as category
from my_table t
inner join params on t.type_0 = params.param
                  or t.type_1 = params.param
                  or t.type_2 = params.param
                  or t.type_3 = params.param
```

| id | param | category |
| --- | --- | --- |
| id_1 | type_max | H |
| id_1 | type_min | VH |
| id_1 | type_three | VL |
| id_1 | type_four | VH |
| id_2 | type_max | VH |
| id_2 | type_min | VL |
| id_2 | type_three | H |
| id_2 | type_four | L |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/10aE-FYr)